# How to judge a selector is contained in a protocol in objc? thanks

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to forwarding all UITableViewDelegate method to another object for some reason 。 Here is the code I wrote , but because there are so many methods in UITableViewDelegate.I have to write to many if else compare for each method.

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{    
    NSString* selector = NSStringFromSelector(aSelector);
    if ([selector isEqualToString:@"tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:"])
    {
        return self.outDelegate;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];

    }
}
```

And I think there is a better solution to do this.can I do it like below,how to test aSelector is Defined in aProtocol or not

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{    
    if (**aSelector is Defined in aProtocol**)
    {
        return self.outDelegate;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];

    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, pointer equality works for selectors: `@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) == aSelector`.

Comment: You may need to drop down into the runtime. see: [`protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList).

Comment: Why do you not just set the `UITableView`'s delegate to 'true' delegate (`self.outDelegate`) in the first place?

Comment: @stonesam92 because the UITableViewDelegate is conform to UIScrollViewDelegate and I want to seperate this two protocols  in different delegate

Comment: @stonesam92 in fact ,I was writing a pull&refresh view as a tableView. so i have to do sth with UIScrollViewDelegate in the refreshView ,and do the UITableViewDelegate things in the controller, so I want separate these two delegate, maybe it's not a good idea:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a C array of the methods in a protocol using `protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList`:

```
int numOfMethods;
struct objc_method_description * method_description_list;
method_description_list = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(@protocol(protocolName), 
    YES, YES, &numOfMethods)
```

The number of descriptions in the array is now stored in the `numOfMethods` variable. You can then iterate through this array and check whether the selector for each method is equal to the current selector using `==` rather than converting the selectors to strings:

```
for (int i=0; i<numOfMethods; i++) {
    if (aSelector == method_description_list[i].name) 
        //forward to other delegate
    else
        return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}
```

Note that you will need to do `free(method_description_list)` to reclaim the memory it occupies once you are done with it.

There is no point in recreating and freeing it every time `forwardingTargetForSelector:` is called, so you might want to do something like turning it into an iVar and creating it in `init`, and then `free`ing it in `dealloc`, since the protocol is very unlikely to change over the lifetime of this object

Comment: NOTE: [sel_isEqual is equivalent to ==](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/sel_isEqual).

Comment: You need to restructure things a bit here, you must `free(method_description_list)` at the end, so you can't `return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector]` in the middle.

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary to recreate the list on every method call, so I assumed you would create the array in `init` and then `free` it in `dealloc`, but I will edit the post to make this explicit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `respondsToSelector:` to check if a delegate has the selector

Also, you could use `conformsToProtocol:` in combination with respondsToSelector: as -

```
if([delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)] && [delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(aMethod)])
    {
        //send message;
    }
```

Comment: thanks , but i think these two condition is not enough, because there may still be some selectors i don't want to forwarding , so I think i have a judge  selector is contained in protocol first

Comment: This (and most other answers) doesn't actually address the question. OP doesn't want to check if the delegate conforms to a given protocol, they (for an unknown reason) want to check if an incoming message is part of a protocol and, if so, forward the message to another object (`self.outDelegate`). This answer will end up forwarding every message the delegate responds to (which includes all of the standard `NSObject` methods, like `description` and possibly even `init`)

Answer (score 0):

Check like this -

```
if([delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(yourProtocolName)])
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Awesome what is it? Please add detail to your answer and don't just post code. The reason being is user might not know what that code does so want it explained. So please add detail. BTW I know exactly what that is.

Answer (score 0):

When you want perform this kind of forwardInvocation and delegate method validation you can use "respondToSelector" and "conformsToProtocol" methods and do the respective ForwardInvocation process.

Answer (score 0):

In UIKit, Apple do this in UIUserNotificationRestrictedAlertViewProxy's respondsToSelector to check isAlertViewDelegateMethod but I have modified the code to work with the UITableViewDelegate so here you go:

```
BOOL isTableViewDelegateMethod(SEL selector) {
    struct objc_method_description desc;
    desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UITableViewDelegate), selector, NO, YES);
    if(desc.name){
        return YES;
    }
    desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UITableViewDelegate), selector, YES, YES);
    if(desc.name){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{    
    if (isTableViewDelegateMethod(aSelector))
    {
        return self.outDelegate;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];

    }
}
```

And you may want to also check UITableViewDataSource since table views have two delegates.